# Stack Level too deep ruby serializer without serializer on second level

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, activemodel

I'm a newbie in ruby and I'm stuck on this strange error.
I'm getting stack level too deep when ever I hit this controller although only one of my object has a serializer.

I have got the following controller

```
def get_class
    @class_sections = ClassSection.all
    @class_sections = ClassSection.filter_by_class(@class_section.school_class.id).limit(nil)

    if @class_sections.present?
        render json: {
                class_sections: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(@class_sections, each_serializer: AdminClassSectionSerializer),
                class: @class_section.class
        }
    else
        render json: {message: "no Class Section found", status: 400}, status: 400
    end
end
```

My Serializer:

```
class AdminClassSectionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :section, :faculty

    belongs_to :faculty
    belongs_to :section

end
```

class, faculty and section don't have a serializer but still it is giving me stack level too deep. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have some kind of circular reference in your structure?

Comment: @tadman no not currently since both of the relations i.e. faculty and section don't have a serializer so they should return just Ids of their relations

Comment: It might be worth having a closer look at what you're serializing to see if there's something unexpected in there. Really hard to say from here, externally, with no access to that data.

Comment: What's `.limit(nil)` supposed to be doing here? It's also odd you're fetching all records, then re-fetching into the same variable, throwing out the earlier results.

Comment: `.limit(nil)` can remove a limit from a predefined scope.

Comment: @tadman that .all was just unnecessary code I fogot to remove.

Comment: @Ashley Ah, good point.

Comment: @tadman it was due to the keyword class I didn't knew we can't use it.